# What happens if I turn an animated Thespian's Stage into another land during combat?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have [Thespian's Stage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThespian%27s%5d%2b%5bStage%5d) in play copying [Raging Ravine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRaging%20Ravine%5d). I animate Thespian's Stage, give it vigilance in some way, and attack. My opponent flashes in [Ambush Viper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAmbush%20Viper%5d) and blocks. I decide I don't want to trade. Can I activate Thespian's Stage to copy a non-animated land and get out of combat that way? What happens to the damage?

Gatherer doesn't say anything about this - only that I need to activate the animation costs after Thespian's Stage has copied a land.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot turn it into another land to remove it from combat.  The issue is due to layers.

Layer 1 is copy effects (Thespian's Stage).

Layer 4 is type changing effects (Raging Ravine's ability).

Since it is still the **same object**, both layers are applied in order.  So, for layer 1 you have a Thespian's Stage that is copying a Raging Ravine that is copying a land (say, a Forest).  Then you apply the type changing effect in layer 4 that turns it into a 3/3 creature.

So, you'd end up with a 3/3 Creature Land - Forest (with a +1/+1 counter from attacking as Raging Ravine)

> 613.1a Layer 1: Copy effects are applied. See rule 706, “Copying Objects.”
>
> 613.1b Layer 2: Control-changing effects are applied.
>
> 613.1c Layer 3: Text-changing effects are applied. See rule 612, “Text-Changing Effects.”
>
> 613.1d Layer 4: Type-changing effects are applied. These include effects that change an object’s card type, subtype, and/or supertype.
>
> 613.1e Layer 5: Color-changing effects are applied.
>
> 613.1f Layer 6: Ability-adding effects, ability-removing effects, and effects that say an object can’t have an ability are applied.
>
> 613.1g Layer 7: Power- and/or toughness-changing effects are applied.

Comment: Good answer, but you may want to pull in some CR references so that people can see how it is actually worded and dive a bit deeper if they wish too.

Comment: Wow, Magic is complicated. I don't understand your answer I'm afraid. Do you mean that Thespian's Stage turns into Raging Ravine first, then it turns into (say) a basic Forest that is still a 3/3 creature with a +1/+1 counter until end of turn?

Comment: @Allure Correct. Essentially, the "turn land into creature" is still affecting the Thespian Stage.

Comment: @Allure MtG is relatively straight-forward for 95% of the game if you know how phases, priority and the stack work. That last 5% is full of corner-cases and head-scratchers which is why the CR is massive and why layers are so spooky.

Comment: Note that this *would* work with Dryad Arbor; it fails in other cases because the ability makes the land a creature for some duration that doesn't end when transforming.